# I have 2 problems with Android Studio I can't run my app

Tags: android, android-studio

Well, the problems are that when I build the apk and install it on any phone it says that it did install it but the button that says "open" it appears disabled and doesn't let me open the app and when I search for the app it doesn't apper on the device and when I search on the apps that are installed it does appear on the list...anyone knows why?

The other problem is when I try to run my app on the device instead of run it on the emulator it says that the app is launched on the device but nothing happens on the device, the only way I can test it is on the Android Studio emulator could anyone help me please?

Comment: did you tick the box in Security Settings that says "Unknown Sources" ?

Comment: sorry i've already solved haha i compared it with another app that i have and saw the android manifest in both  and the thing that i was missing is this :'<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>'

Comment: You can check correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cause that you don't see app in your phone is that you haven't set any icon for it in manifest. I had the same problem. 
One possibility that you can't run your app on your phone is Android version of your phone. Maybe your app isn't proper for that version.